# wxpython: how to stop repetition of colorbar along with area bar while audio signal analysis

Tags: wxpython, signal-processing

[image] after loading new signal at every time the colorbar gets repeated.
    def draw_areagram_data(self):
        """Draw the object data into an XY plot and refresh the plot"""

```
    # self.figure_areagram.clear()
    self.axes_areagram.clear()
    self.area_bar = self.axes_areagram.pcolormesh(self.area_t, self.area_f / 10, self.ag_matrix, cmap='gray')
    # area_bar = self.axes_areagram.imshow(self.ag_matrix, origin='upper', cmap="gray", aspect='auto')
    area_bar = self.axes_areagram.pcolormesh(self.area_t, self.area_f / 10, self.ag_matrix, cmap='gray')
    # self.cbar.remove()
    # self.figure_areagram.clear()


    # cbar = self.figure_areagram.colorbar(area_bar, ax=self.axes_areagram, orientation='vertical', pad=0.02,visible='on')
    # cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=7)
    self.cbar = self.figure_areagram.colorbar(area_bar, ax=self.axes_areagram, orientation='vertical', pad=0.02)
    self.canvas_areagram.Update()
    self.canvas_areagram.close_event(self.cbar)
    self.axes_areagram.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
    self.axes_areagram.set_ylabel('L-G Dist. (norm)', fontname="Arial", fontsize=10, labelpad=10)
    self.axes_areagram.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(6))
    # self.axes_areagram.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    self.canvas_areagram.draw()
    self.canvas_areagram.Refresh()
    # if self.colorbar is None:
    #     self.colorbar = self.figure_areagram.colorbar(area_bar, ax=self.axes_areagram, orientation='vertical', pad=0.02,visible='on')
    # else:
    self.cbar.update_ticks()
    # self.axes_areagram.clf()
    #
```